# Rails 3.1 Undefined Method with has_many & belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many

I am having issues with my Rails 3.1 app. I have two controllers & models, named counties/county and towns/town.

The county model has `has_many :towns` and the town model has `belongs_to :county`.

I am trying to show the County name on the Towns index page to show the title as 'Towns in -county-name-'. However, when I put `%h1 Towns in #{@towns.county.name}` I get a `undefined method 'county'` error.

The towns controller for index is

```
def index
    @towns = Town.all
end
```

For the county controller:

```
def index
    @counties = County.all
end
```

My `routes.rb` is

```
resources :counties, :path => "/locations" do
    resources :towns, :path => "/"
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Using this in my towns/index view and it shows the `town.county.id` and `town.county.name`:

```
- @towns.each do |town|
  %tr
    %td= town.county.id
    %td= town.county.name
    %td= town.name
    %td= town.description
    %td= town.slug
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with states and countries (vs town and counties).
For your town migration, did you have an integer to reference the county (see **county_id** below)

```
class CreateTowns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :towns do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :county_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your app/views/town/index.html.erb you can do a County.find

```
 %tr
    %td= town.county.id
    %td= County.find(town.county_id).name
    %td= town.name
    %td= town.description
    %td= town.slug
```

Comment: The County.find fixed it for me =]

Answer (score 0):

`@towns` is a collection of... towns. Not an individual town. A collection of towns doesn't have a county (according to your model), only an individual town has a county.

If you're on the towns index page and are trying to show the towns in a county, it's not clear what you're really doing--are you listing the county for each town, and trying to show the *other* towns in that county? That would be `town.county.towns` (but you'd likely want to remove the "current" town).

I don't know why you show anything for the `counties` controller, since you're on a `towns` page. If you want to get all the counties *also*, then do so, but the county controller isn't involved.

Comment: OK, I have tried `Town.county.name` and `@town.county.name` but it shows the same message

Comment: This is for a wedding website. I want to show the Counties available in the UK and then under each County, I want to then show the Towns available in that County :)  Showing the Towns for that County isn't working either

Comment: @deanpcmad If you want to show the counties, what are you doing on the towns index? Sounds like you're talking about the counties index.

Comment: @deanpcmad There probably isn't a `@town`; if you're iterating over `@towns` you might have a `town`. `Town.county.name` is right out.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion. The /locations page shows the counties available. Then clicking on that location, eg, /locations/hampshire, I want to show the towns available and then go to , /locations/hampshire/southampton. The part I am stuck on it trying to get the County name to show on the Towns index page showing which Towns are in the selected County.

Also I have the problem where any County I choose, shows all the Towns. I'm guessing this may be linked?